# Example of unbounded compact set?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In a metric space $\Bbb{R}^k$ a compact set is a closed and bounded set. In general metric spaces a compact set is still closed, but do exist sets which are compact and unbounded, right? (otherwise the definition would be equivalent to $\Bbb{R}^k$). Could you give me some examples?

OBS.: I haven't taken any topology course yet, just real analysis.

Comment: "limited" should be "bounded"

Comment: The implication $\text{compact}\implies\text{bounded}$ holds in arbitrary metric spaces (but the implication $\text{compact}\implies\text{closed}$ does not; it does hold in Hausdorff spaces, however).

Comment: @symplectomorphic Metric spaces are Hausdorff.

Comment: @amsmath: whoops, sorry: I was thinking of arbitrary topological spaces in that half of the sentence; you're right of course (wish I could edit comments after 5 minutes...).

Comment: Also the "if" of the "if and only if" is not true.  With the discrete metric  all sets are closed and bounded but only finite sets are compact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compact sets in metric spaces are always bounded. Let $k \in K$ be an arbitrary point, then the sequence of open balls $\{x \mid d(k, x) < n\}$ is an open cover for $K$. By compactness, we can find a finite subcover and therefore there is a finite value $N$ so that $d(x, k) < N$ holds for all $x \in K$.

However, the other way around is in general false: Not every bounded closed set is compact.

Comment: so the "difference" between compact sets in $\Bbb{R}^k$ and in general metric spaces is that in $\Bbb{R}^k$ bounded and closed $\iff$ compact and in general metric space just $\Leftarrow$ holds?

Comment: @HugoValadão That's correct.

Answer (score 3):

In a metric space $X$ a set is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded.

A metric space is totally bounded if for each $\epsilon>0$ exists $x_1,\dots x_n\in X$ such that $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^nB_\epsilon(x_i)$. A totally bounded space is bounded.

So you have to ask a stronger property.

As an example of consider $\mathbb{N}$ with the discrete metric, it is bounded, but is not compact as it is not totally bounded.

Answer (score 1):

You are not undersating the fact that in topological spaces (in genereal) just $\leftarrow$ holds... but in $R$^k $\iff$ holds